# Expand/reshape dimension of column of Pandas Series

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, shapes

I want to expand a `pandas` series from one to three dimension. Below `print(np.array(xs).shape)` gives me an output of `(2,)` and I would like the shape of `np.array(xs)` to be `(2,3,3)`, what should I do?

```
import pandas as pd
x = []
x.append(np.ones((3,3)))
x.append(np.zeros((3,3)))

xs = pd.Series(x)
print(np.array(xs).shape)
```

Any reply is appreciated!

note: I know `np.array(x)` would give me the desired output and shape, however I am given `xs` in the first place. The expected output should be `print(np.array(x))` whose shape is `(2,3,3)`.

```
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

      [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Comment: Can you print a picture your expected output?

Comment: @ScottBoston, just edited!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can convert the Series to dataframes and then concat and convert to numpy array. Finally reshape it to the shape you need.

```
pd.concat(xs.apply(pd.DataFrame).tolist()).values.reshape(2,3,3)
Out[1081]: 
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Comment: You are welcome @Francis. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `Series` to `list` and then to `array`:

```
print (np.array(xs.tolist()))
[[[ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]]

print (np.array(xs.tolist()).shape)
(2, 3, 3)
```